# What is an overview of arguments for and against the historicity of the resurrection of Jesus?

Tags: history, reference-request, resurrection-of-jesus, historical-jesus

What is an overview of arguments for and against the [historicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historicity) of the resurrection of Jesus? Was Jesus' resurrection a historical fact? What do scholars and historians have to say about all this? Is there consensus among the majority of scholars or is this still a controversial topic?

Comment: Alas, I don't know, which is why that was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Questions shouldn't ask for both sides like this. And if you really want answers from historians then you should ask at [history.se].

Comment: @curiousdannii - let's see if the question prospers: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/63490/was-the-resurrection-of-jesus-a-historical-fact

Comment: @curiousdannii - update: it didn't :(

Comment: Is the documented record of reliable witnesses not 'historical' enough ? What more evidence do you want ?

Comment: @NigelJ - many skeptics would consider that insufficient/inconclusive evidence.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator  Indeed. That is what skeptics do - disbelieve valid evidence. And where does it get them ? _We are not of them that draw back unto perdition, but of them believe to the saving of the soul._ Heb 10:9.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I'm personally shocked to see the bias of the History.SE community to your question, as just in about 15 minutes I could find plenty of scholarly and peer reviewed works about the historicity of the resurrection done in the past 20 years.  Some scholars often mentioned in the resources I found are NT Wright, [Gary Habermas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Habermas), [John Crossan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Dominic_Crossan), and [Bart Ehrman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bart_D._Ehrman) all of whom are aware of the strict standard of historicity.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator The few I found in 15 minutes : 1) 2020 Routledge book [Investigating the Resurrection of Jesus Christ: A New Transdisciplinary Approach](https://library.oapen.org/handle/20.500.12657/38236), 2) 2010 MA in Religious Studies thesis [Jesus's Resurrection: A Historical Investigation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254635378), 3) Habermas's paper [Resurrection Research from 1975 to the Present](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/58822082.pdf), 4) 2019 book [Did Jesus Rise from the Dead?: Historical and Theological Reflections](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0198838964)

Comment: @GratefulDisciple And Bart Ehrman is not a professing Christian.

Comment: @MikeBorden Yes, so an ideal candidate for the *against* position.  Neither does Crossan.  Christian scholars who adhere to the secular historicity standard then use them as foil to poke holes into their deficient historiography since the subject matter necessarily need special handling for a reasonable person.  Christian scholars in the past few decades have advanced their academic respectability way beyond popular apologists in the 80s like Josh McDowell.  It's just many people are not aware of this, hence probably the bias in History.SE.

Comment: "After that, he was seen of above five hundred brethren at once; of whom the greater part remain unto this present, but some are fallen asleep."  Even scholars that disbelieve in the resurrection will admit that they believe that Paul believed it.

Answer (score 2):

Simon Greenleaf, one of the principal founders of the Harvard School of Law and author of the 3 volume "A Treatise On The Law of Evidence", which is still considered a classic of American jurisprudence, also wrote a book entitled "An Examination of the Testimony of the Four Evangelists by the Rules of Evidence Administered in Courts of Justice."

In this book he applies U.S. trial court rules to the accounts of the 4 gospel eyewitness accounts and finds them not only acceptable witnesses, but exemplary as pertaining to the life, death, and resurrection of Jesus Christ.

There is far too much to even begin to cut and paste into an answer but a full, free pdf is available many places including here:

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/34989/34989-pdf.pdf

Answer (score -1):

**General sources of evidence for**

Wolfhart Pannenberg --
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfhart_Pannenberg

Lee Strobel --
The Case for Easter: A Journalist Investigates Evidence for the Resurrection

**Additional Evidence for**

The two words for love in John 21:15 has long been debated.  The second word that Peter used is the verb whose noun form means *friend*.  Sometimes people bring up that Jesus most likely spoke these words in an Aramaic influenced Hebrew rather than Greek, followed by dismissing the difference.  However, Samuel Olyan wrote in Friendship in the Hebrew Bible:

> Although the biblical text has no word for “friendship,” there are a number of words for “friend.” Most common is rēaʿ and related nouns such as rēʿâ, raʿyâ, rēʿeh, and mērēaʿ, each apparently derived either from a root r ʿ h or a root r ʿʿ, both meaning something like “to associate with” or “to affiliate with,” suggesting a voluntary dimension to friendship." (Olyan, S. M. (2017). Friendship in the Hebrew Bible. (J. J. Collins, Ed.) (p. 4). New Haven; London: Yale University Press.)

What is interesting about this root is one of it's homonyms means to feed sheep, and is the verb used to translate such in John 21:15 in the Syriac (Aramaic) Peshitta and Hebrew translations of the New Testament.  Thus, Jesus made a play on Peter's words.  This play on words is too striking to be coincidence.  Not only does it substantiate the authenticity of the account, but also **the historicity of the resurrected Jesus**.

**General evidence against**

Generally historians reject history based on miracles and unique events inconsistent with scientific principles, which are based on generalizations.  The resurrection of Jesus is a unique event that can't be investigated by similar events.  Its evidence depends on eye witnesses.